# Oracle 11g trigger to replace part of a text string

Tags: triggers, oracle11g, mutating-table

I'm having issues with a trigger that keeps mutating. The goal of the trigger is when a file path is updated change part of the string. Here is what I have so far, it compiles just fine.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TAU_ATTACHMENTS
AFTER UPDATE
ON ATTACHMENTS
FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
  IF :new.PATH LIKE 'file://Y:%' THEN   
    UPDATE ATTACHMENTS SET PATH = REPLACE(:new.PATH, 'file://Y:','file://\\MPS7536');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

When I do a test of updating a single row I get the usual mutating table error. Any advice? I'd be extremely grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are obviously want to modify value of a column in trigger before storing it. But instead the provided code is trying to update whole `attachments` table. You can modify the value of record which is being updated like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TAU_ATTACHMENTS
BEFORE UPDATE
ON ATTACHMENTS
FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
  IF :new.PATH LIKE 'file://Y:%' THEN   
    :new.PATH = REPLACE(:new.PATH, 'file://Y:','file://\\MPS7536');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Note that this should be `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger.

Comment: It worked perfectly thank you! It's always the little things that get me. :)